# Как убрать формат ввода даты в Chrome дд.мм.гггг?

Tags: html, google-chrome

Когда создаю поле для ввода даты, примерно такое:

```
<input type="date" ... >
```

Хром показывает формат ввода даты `дд.мм.гггг`. 
Как его можно убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какую конечную цель вы преследуете? Убрать плейсхолдер?

Comment: Да. Однако `<input type="date" placeholder=" ">` не работает. Хром вообще на плейсхолдер никак не раегирует.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<input name="date" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value)this.type='text'">
```

Comment: Ruslan_K, была такая мысль. Но нежелательно, чтобы введенная дата при уходе фокуса становилась невидимой.

Comment: и правда не в тему, нашел другой вариант